# How to check if application was deployed on a specific managed server?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, wlst

I use following wlst command in order to check if application was already deployed before:

```
oldApplication = find(name=d['name'], type='AppDeployment')
```

But it does not show that application was deployed on a specific server.
How can I find that application was deployed on a specific managed server?

Answer (score 1):

oldApplication will be an AppDeployment MBean, which has the "targets" attribute.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13951/mbeans/AppDeploymentMBean.html

oldApplication.targets will return an array of "TargetMBean", which will be the list of servers on which the application is targeted/deployed.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me and might help you:

```
print 'stopping and undeploying ...'

try:
    stopApplication('WebApplication')
    undeploy('WebApplication')
    print 'Redeploying...'

except Exception:
    print 'Deploy...'

deploy('WebApplication', '/home/saeed/project/test/WebApplication/dist/WebApplication.war')
startApplication('WebApplication2')
```